# Не работает while

Tags: php, файлы

У меня не работает while. Я уже долгое время проверяю и все сводится к тому, что:

1. Есть пременная $lig. Ее значение получается из того что я считаю количество ячеек массива $nou. Тут все впорядке. (Должно быть 5, так и получается)
2. Есть переменная $f. Она выводит из цикла. Она не работает. Почему-то вместо тех 5ти раз, которые она должна отработать работает только 2.

Вопрос: сам я дурак или что-то с программой не так?

Не работующий отрывок:

```html
$file = 'Data/Users/'.$_COOKIE['id'].'/chats.txt';
$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$arr = file($file);
$nou = $arr;
fclose($f);

$lig = count($nou);



$f = 0;
$r = 0;

while($f <= $lig){

$n = trim($nou[$f]);  
                                                                 
$file = 'Data/Messages/Chats/'.$n.'/user_in.txt';

$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$k = file($file);
fclose($f);




if($_GET['id'] === trim($k['0'])){
 $r = 1;
}
else{
 if($_GET['id'] === trim($k['1'])){
  $r = 1;
 }
}

if($r === 1){
 $i = $n;
}

$f++;


}
```

$r после этого применяется так: 
Есть if, который создает новый чат, если $r = 0, а если = 1 - пропускает.

Comment: поменяйте имя переменной для `$f = fopen($file, 'r');`

Comment: @Александр Корниенко а зачем создаётся первая $f ?